# How to set the lang global attribute for <html> inside an external CSS file (.css)

Tags: html, css, attributes, lang

I keep getting a warning message when I try to set the `lang` attribute for the `<html>` element inside a CSS stylesheet (external `.css` file).

Inside the CSS stylesheet, I added the following to set the `lang` attribute for the `<html>` tag:

```css
html {
  lang: "en-US";
}
```

However, my editor (VS code) prompts me with a warning message stating the following:

`Unknown property: 'lang'css(unknownProperties)`

I am not sure if what I did is correct, so I want to know if there is a way to set the `lang` attribute for the `<html>` tag inside a `.css`?

Comment: As you were told, there is no `lang` property in CSS. The `lang` attribute of HTML is also not a style so Cascading **Style** Sheets cannot and should not set that HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we usually use inline styles, we may mistakenly assume that the specific attributes of style are level with other attributes of html, but they are not.

lang is hierarchical with the id, class, style at the same level，and to some extent css is a collection of html style attributes.

You can't change style(css) to change the value of id or class, the same as lang.（at least now）

just use lang inside ele.

I din't found why web used lang as html global attribute why not style attribute but some funny thing.

desripe of dir in mdn:

> This attribute can be overridden by the CSS properties direction and unicode-bidi, if a CSS page is active and the element supports these properties.
>
> As the directionality of the text is semantically related to its content and not to its presentation, it is recommended that web developers use this attribute instead of the related CSS properties when possible. That way, the text will display correctly even on a browser that doesn't support CSS or has the CSS deactivated.

Logically, Lang might be able to fit into style rather than global attributes,but it's one of Global attributes and can't be set in css at least now,so just follow the conventions it when they don't ruin something.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen or heard of setting the language in a CSS file. As far as I'm aware, you should be declaring it at the top of your HTML doc, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <!-- RIGHT HERE -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The only language related property or otherwise I could find for CSS is `:lang()`.

As per W3 Schools:

The `:lang()` selector is used to select elements with a lang attribute with the specified value.

You can read the full page [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp), or on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang), whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know this method. I still want to know if it's possible to set it in the .css file; and if not, why?

Comment: You cannot set language int the CSS file as far as I can tell. You can specify which character set you wish to use. The most common one is UTF-8. You can declare it at the top of your CSS file like so:

`@charset "utf-8";`